# Tengo error Not a JSON Object al intentar deserializar un Json con Gson

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, gson

Es mi primera vez utilizando la libreria Gson para programar una aplicación de escritorio con JavaFX y estoy teniendo un problema que no me permite avanzar con mi proyecto.

Al intentar deserializar un json me lanza un error que dice Not a JSON Object

Este es mi Json:

```
{"id":1,"user_name":"daniel","user_password":"1234"}, 
{"id":3,"user_name":"luis","user_password":"1234"}
```

Este es mi Código para deserializar mi json:

```
public class UsersService implements JsonDeserializer<Users>{

    @Override 
    public Users deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
      JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JsonObject userJson = json.getAsJsonObject(); 

        Long id = userJson.get("id").getAsLong(); 
        String username = userJson.get("user_name").getAsString();
        String password = userJson.get("user_password").getAsString();

        Users users = new Users();
        users.setId(id);
        users.setUsername(username);
        users.setPassword(password);

        return users;
    }    
}
```

Me lanza este error:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at 
com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$358(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [{"id":1,"user_name":"daniel","user_password":"1234"},{"id":3,"user_name":"luis","user_password":"1234"}]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:899)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
    at application.LoginController.actionLogin(LoginController.java:46)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [{"id":1,"user_name":"daniel","user_password":"1234"},{"id":3,"user_name":"luis","user_password":"1234"}]
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:90)
    at application.Http.UsersService.deserialize(UsersService.java:19)
    at application.Http.UsersService.deserialize(UsersService.java:1)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    ... 61 more
```

Estuve buscando como solucionar este problema pero aun no encuentro la forma correcta de hacerlo.
Les agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás pasando un JSON de tipo ARRAY y no un OBJECT

```
//EN VEZ DE ESTO
JsonObject userJson = json.getAsJsonObject();
// ESTE
JsonArray userJson = json.getAsJsonArray();
```

Aquí unos ejemplos:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class TestGson {

private static void deserializeObject(String myJsonString) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    User user = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, User.class);
    System.out.println("Object ===> " + user);
}

private static void deserializeArray(String myJsonString) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    List<User> users = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, List.class);
    System.out.println("Array ===> " + users);
}

private static void parseAndDeserializeArray(JsonElement json) {
    System.out.println("Array parse ===> " + json.getAsJsonArray());
}

private static void parseAndDeserializeObject(JsonElement json) {
    System.out.println("Object parse ===> " + json.getAsJsonObject());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // JSON Input example
    String myJsonArrayString = "[{\"id\":1,\"user_name\":\"daniel\",\"user_password\":\"1234\"},{\"id\":3,\"user_name\":\"luis\",\"user_password\":\"1234\"}]";
    String myJsonObjectString = "{\"id\":3,\"user_name\":\"luis\",\"user_password\":\"1234\"}";

    deserializeArray(myJsonArrayString);
    deserializeObject(myJsonObjectString);

    // parse to object from json object string
    JsonElement element1 = new JsonParser().parse(myJsonObjectString);
    parseAndDeserializeObject(element1);

    // parse to object from json array string
    JsonElement element2 = new JsonParser().parse(myJsonArrayString);
    parseAndDeserializeArray(element2);

}
```

}